# Python: include source file literally

Tags: python

Is it possible to literally include a Python source within another source file? Something of the form:

foo1.py:

```
a = 5
#include foo2.py
print( "Good bye!" )
```

foo2.py:

```
print( str(a) )
```

Is such a construction possible? I have got a piece of code that I would like to run in different source files. Do I need to wrap this in a function?

Comment: Yes, wrap it in a function, import it and call it when needed.

Comment: `from foo1 import a`

Comment: Python itself does not. You would need to use a preprocessor like `cpp` or `m4`.

Comment: The closest you can get to literal inclusion is `from foo2 import *`. But you will have scoping issues. So, no.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille That's not _literal inclusion_.

Comment: @DYZ My 'yes' was an answer to the OP's last question, not the first. Maybe I should have made it clearer..